# Replace updated version strings in files via Python

Tags: python, regex, string, replace

I want to use Python to replace version strings in `foopkg/__init__.py`:

```py
__version__ = "0.1.3"
```

… and in `setup.py`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os.path import join
from setuptools import find_packages, setup


version = "0.1.3"

entry_points = {
    "console_scripts": [
        "say-foo = fooproj.foo:foo"
    ]
}

[...]
```

The absolute paths to these two files, and the new version number, are passed to the following function via the `file_path` and `new_version` arguments, respectively:

```py
def update_version_strings(file_path, new_version):
    VERSION_REGEX = re.compile(
        r"(^(__)?version(__)?\s*=\s*\")(?P<version>\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\"$"
    )
    with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(
            re.sub(
                VERSION_REGEX,
                lambda match: '{}{}"'.format(match.group(1), new_version),
                content,
            )
        )
        f.truncate()
```

Invoking this function via:

```py
update_version_strings("/path/to/foopkg/__init__.py", "0.1.4")
```

… correctly replaces the version number line in `foopkg/__init__.py` to `__version__ = "0.1.4"`, but `update_version_strings("/path/to/setup.py", "0.1.4")` yields no change to the `setup.py` file.

I imagine that the fault lies with some combination of `VERSION_REGEX` and the `lambda match` directives. I am admittedly not well versed in regular expressions and have almost certainly done this in a less-than-optimal fashion.

What is the optimal way to replace these two different version string formats and write the changes to the respective files?

*Bonus points*: It would be great to also support single-quote-style, such that version numbers in `__version__ = '0.1.3'` and `version = '0.1.3'` strings would also be properly replaced.  (^_^)

Comment: Are you doing this for releasing sdist/bdist and update version on each release?

Comment: I am using Poetry to increment the version in `pyproject.toml`, but I also want to increment version strings in other files since Poetry cannot currently do that. I understand that there are numerous CLI tools that can increment version strings, but for this use case I want to avoid adding another dependency and prefer to increment these extra version strings within the existing code environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In files with multiple lines, the key to matching the beginning/end of a line is the `re.M` or [`re.MULTILINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) directive. The following function replaces version numbers for both `version = "0.1.3"` and `__version__ = '0.1.3'` string formats — covering both single and double quotation marks — in files that may have multiple lines:

```
def update_version_strings(file_path, new_version):
    version_regex = re.compile(r"(^_*?version_*?\s*=\s*['\"])(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)", re.M)
    with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(
            re.sub(
                version_regex,
                lambda match: "{}{}".format(match.group(1), new_version),
                content,
            )
        )
        f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following approach for *two different version string formats* (it also covers single/double quotes):

```
def update_version_strings(file_path, new_version):
    version_regex = re.compile(r"(^_*?version_*?\s*=\s*['\"])(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)")
    with open(file_path, "r+") as f:
        content = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(
            re.sub(
                version_regex,
                lambda match: '{}{}'.format(match.group(1), new_version),
                content,
            )
        )
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: This functions as expected but has unearthed another problem: the version strings are only replaced when the version string is the first line in the file. Sometimes that is true (as currently in `__init__.py`), but in files such as `setup.py` there are many other lines before and after the version string line. I have updated the example contents of `setup.py` in my original question to reflect this. Might you know how to modify this function such that _any_ lines containing version strings are appropriately updated?